# How to calculate bitcoin days destroyed percentage

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin-days-destroyed

I understand the concept of bitcoin days destroyed but on the wiki

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Days_Destroyed

And the site calculating it

http://abe.bitcoinstats.org:2750/

They give a percentage which is the coin days vs block number. Can someone run me through this calculation.

```
Block  | Age (days) | Coins Created | Avg Coin Age | %CoinDD
210842 | 1430.57    | 10521062.02   | 420.84       | 37.2271%
```

This was a recent sample from abe and I can't arrive at 37.2271%

Answer (score 1):

The [graph is a histogram](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bitcoin_Days_Destroyed#Graph_of_Percentage_of_Bitcoin_Days_Destroyed) showing the percentage of total Days Destroyed from the measured period for each block. Thus it is a distribution of dormancy over the period, since block numbers are ascending forward in time.

To arrive at the percentage in your example, you need to divide the Days Destroyed for that example block by the total of the Days Destroyed for the period being graphed.